# Correctly index list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I'd like to be able to index a multi-line string such as the hangman below to chose the correct string based on the number of words incorrect. When I use the code below it does not index the correct figure and I'm not sure why. Thanks.

```
a=list({

'''
     |
     O
    \|


''',

'''
     |
     O
    \|/
     |

''',

'''
     |
     O
    \|/
     |
    /
''',

'''
     |
     O
    \|/
     |
    / \
'''
});

for i in range(4):
    print(a[i])
```

Output:

```
     |
     O
    \|/
     |



     |
     O
    \|/




     |
     O
    \|/
     |
    /

     |
     O
    \|/
     |
    /
```

Comment: You can turn your list into a dictionary and add a 'order' field. Alternatively, you could always sort based on number of non-space characters in your string.

Comment: You build a list from a set, which is unordered. Remove the curly braces: `a = ["...", ...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want order to be preserved, don't use `{}` notation because this creates a fundamentally unordered container (either a `set` or a `dict`—in your case, a `set`).  You then convert it to a `list`, but too late—order is already lost.

Instead, just say:

```
a = [
  """"
  first string
  """,
  # ...
]
```

Square brackets denote a `list`, which is an ordered container.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[

'''
     |
     O
    \|


''',

'''
     |
     O
    \|/
     |

''',

'''
     |
     O
    \|/
     |
    /
''',

'''
     |
     O
    \|/
     |
    / \\
'''
]

for i in range(4):
    print(a[i])
```

Comment: Thanks man, other guy explained which is why I accepted his but good answer here too